# Software for extracting data from eight DVD-Rs at the same time

Tags: optical-media, data-transfer

I'm assemblying [hardware for extracting data from eight DVD-Rs at the same time](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1728/hardware-for-extracting-data-from-eight-dvd-rs-at-the-same-time). Now I need software that are able to automatically transfer the data on the optical media to a filesystem.

This would be the user story:

1. Configure path for destination file-system
2. Insert DVD-R in eight different optical drives
3. Copy data files from the eight drives to destination filesystem
4. Eject DVD-R from the eight drives

It should run on Windows 64-bit, Linux or OS X.
The copying of data files should preserve file-information.
As long as the software solves the task, it does not matter if it has a user-interface. I.e. it could run on command-line tool or as a script.

Are there any solutions available for this?

Comment: What operating system? Command-line or GUI?

Comment: Are you talking about copying the __files__ from the DVD-Rs or creating an ISO/Other __image__ of each of the 8 DVD-Rs as this makes a big difference?

Comment: @steve-barnes In what sense would it make a difference to copy files or to an image? In the end I would like to have access to the files. Could it be a better option to make ISO images, and then transfer files from the image as a later step?

Comment: @JoachimBratteli Different software is required to copy an image to that needed to copy a directory tree, copying and image is a single operation copying the tree is one operation for each file and directory. Probably the best option is to copy the images and then mount as required.